# adding homework to a school's website

Tags: customization

I have a school website - pickeringschool.org -  that I am changing over to WordPress. This is no problem except that I want to add the functionality that allows the teachers to add daily homework [like here](http://pickeringschool.org/cluster51.php?action=homework)> I am a novice developer so any suggestions, tutorials, etc would be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

See if this plugin suitable for your needs.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/weekly-schedule/screenshots/

Answer (score 0):

[Scholarpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/buddypress-courseware/) plugin for buddypress is for managing courses and also allows for class pages, schedules, discussions.